# How to activate IWiFiDirectDevice in Win32 Console APP using WRL?

Tags: windows-runtime, wifi-direct, wrl

I want to use WinRT API for WiFi Direct from Windows 10 SDK in Win32 Console Application. I know about C++/CX (and even made some progress going that way), but still want to make it work without this extension.

My problem is that I can't activate IWifiDirectDevice interface (from ABI::Windows::Devices::WiFiDirect) to access IWifiDirectDeviceStatics that provides an GetDeviceSelector method.

```
HStringReference strDevice(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_WiFiDirect_WiFiDirectDevice);

ComPtr<IInspectable> insp;
hr = RoActivateInstance(strDevice.Get(), insp.GetAddressOf());
```

This code ends up with E_NOTIMPL as a result. In Microsoft's [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973459.aspx) they used factories for activation, but ABI::Windows::Devices::WiFiDirect namespace has no  factories.

Worth mentioning that IWifiDirectAdvertisementPublisher works just fine when activated the way I wrote before.

So how to activate IWifiDirectDevice from WRL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectDevice` is not an activatable class. You can see that by looking at `windows.devices.wifidirect.idl`.

You will need to use the static methods, e.g.:

```
HStringReference strDevice(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_WiFiDirect_WiFiDirectDevice);

ComPtr<IWiFiDirectDeviceStatics> wiFiDirectDeviceStatics;
hr = Windows::Foundation::GetActivationFactory(
    strDevice.Get(),
    &wiFiDirectDeviceStatics);

ComPtr<IWiFiDirectDevice> wiFiDirectDevice;
ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<WiFiDirectDevice*>> asyncOperation;
hr = wiFiDirectDeviceStatics->FromIdAsync(deviceId.Get(), &asyncOperation);
```

Consider taking a look at the [Wi-Fi Direct sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/714722f53c3ae270f634f54cb2740411f6b11032/Samples/WiFiDirect).

Comment: That is so unclear(I mean API), to init WiFiDirectDeviceStatic I need to pass it to GetActivationFactory... I supposed that GetActivationFactory should produce a factory...

Comment: @Yrchgrchh Yes, it's confusing. Sorry. GetActivationFactory is really GetStaticStuff, but the idea was that most of the time you are getting the factory, so they named it after what most people will use it for.